# Parameter comment must be on the next line at position 1

Tags: 7, coding-standards

I review my module code with http://pareview.sh and it returns an error:

Line #94 - ERROR | Parameter comment must be on the next line at position 1

```
/**
 * Fetch node object properties. //<---  THIS IS LINE #94 
 * 
 * @param object $node contains information about campaign.
 * 
 * @return array
 *   Webform properties.
*/
```

http://pareview.sh/pareview/httpgitdrupalorgprojectbounceconvertgit

If I add the comment on next line, it says: it requires a blank newline after it.
How to fix this error?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Sorry, but this is not a Drupal issue. This is something between your tool (http://pareview.sh) and pure PHP syntax, so you should ask it on tool's forum / issue queue, or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As pareview is a requirement for full project rights on Drupal.org, I think this is on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it clearly says *Parameter comment must be on the next line at position 1*...

Correct way of documenting your function is..

```
/**
 * Fetch node object properties. 
 *
 * @param object $node 
 *   contains information about campaign.
 * 
 * @return array
 *   Webform properties.
 */
```

For more information on commenting standards check [Drupal Coding Standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#comment) Documentation in D.O